# Running two new circuits to outside backyard (One for swimming pool)

Tags: electrical, backyard

I am looking to run two new circuits outside. Initially it was one circuit for a swimming pool, but I figure since I am doing the run to the other side of the yard, I should run another circuit for yard decorations, tools, etc.

I am going to use a GFCI circuit break for both, and I would like to run the same wires in the same conduit. I planned on making the pool circuit 20amps, and the secondary outlet 15amps. I have metal conduit in the house, and would like to lead out of the house from metal conduit to pvc conduit.

1)For inside the house, is it better to run a separate conduit line for these two circuits, or pull through an existing conduit to save time. Here are pictures of the basement ceiling conduit and breaker box, and the corner of the basement I would like to lead the conduit out at. Is there a circuit spot I need to come out of the house at, or any restrictions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Bring electric out through this corner.
[image]

Would like to run conduit along fence line to corner gate, right side. The other trench in picture is for french drain I am installing. The trench would start from left of picture to fence. Pool will be around that corner as well.
[image]

Trench start from house

2) with the length of the run, about 75ft outside, and then about 40ft to run the wire from the breaker box to the otherside of the basement, then to outside, should I run 12guage wire for both the 20amp and 15amp circuits to reduce any voltage loss? Also, would the wires be 2 neutrals, and 2 hot, and then coming from the outside, 1 ground? What guage should the ground be?

3) can I come out of the house on an angle to shorten the length then with a 45 degree turn, then straight and then a 90 for 4ft, and another 90 for 1ft run then go up to surface mount..

4) how far above ground do the outlets need to be? And can both circuits sit on the same 4x4 post?

5)Anything else I should know?

I have the permit for the pool approved and I was told the electrical is included. I submitted the permit application before I decided to add the extra circuit. Would the second circuit in this scenario usually cover the second circuit inspection since the inspector is basically looking at all the same things?

Thank you!

Comment: Your pictures don't seem to have made it...

Comment: Sorry, had to do it from phone. Should be up now.

Comment: Can you get us sizing and fill data on the conduit you wish to reuse for the indoor run?

Comment: Sure, I dropped the first light bulb housing and see about 6 wires coming through the conduit from breaker box. It is the one farthest left, as the other two seem to go outside, and upstairs. I was thinking of trying to run through this one.

Comment: ^^It's the 3rd picture down and the conduit that is running through light. I was also thinking of feeding all the way through, and coming through the sump pump conduit line if that's possible then head to outside to adjacent wall.

Comment: Are you planning on using THWN wire? What size is the pool pump. With this information we can provide a better answer on the needed conduit size and if needed a recommendation to go to 10 or # 8 awg wire with the 115' wire length. (a 10 amp load needs #10 according to the check I just did). [voltage drop calculator](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm).

Comment: Yes I will be using THWN run to outside pvc conduit. Here is the original thread I had, where @ThreePhaseEel answered a lot of my questions as well: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/111615/running-electric-to-swimming-pool-pump

I wrote this thread because I am trying to understand how to properly run the wire from the breaker box to the outside, and how to properly run 2 circuits now instead of one.  The pump is one of those small intex pumps, I want to be able to upgrade in a couple years to a standard pool and pump, so I was looking to put in a pool circuit to accommodate that.

Answer (score 3):

### Two circuits to the same place must be different.

You can't simply run two 120V general-purpose circuits to an outdoor location or outbuilding.  There must be something that makes one circuit different from the other.  For instance it can be a different voltage (120 vs 240 vs 120/240 split vs MWBC)... Or differently controlled (always-on, on a manual switch, pressure switch, timer, etc.)

For instance you could have a 240v pump working off a pressure switch, a 240V always-hot circuit powering heater on a thermostat in a shed, a general purpose 120V circuit, and two lighting circuits controlled by different switches.

### Separate neutrals required; shared ground is fine

In fact, certain types of conduit are permitted to be used *as* the ground wire.   The ground needs to be sized for the largest circuit.

### Upsizing wires is a good idea for these distances

It's not required to upsize wires for long distances, but it certainly helps machines perform better and reduce breaker trips.

Once you commit to 12 AWG you might as well breaker for 20A.

### No more than four

You can have a maximum four circuits per conduit.   240V/120V circuits count as one circuit.  MWBCs count as one circuit.

If you want to have more than four circuits, you can do up to ten if you bump all the circuits up a wire size (well, 2 sizes, 12 to 10 etc.).  This applies to circuits up to 20A.  For larger, the math is more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Harper. I am confused to your first statement. A swimming pool pump must have its own dedicated circuit, so I figured the only other way to add another outlet along with the pool pump outlet was to run two circuits then instead of one.

Comment: The risk is of the AHJ saying he sees two constant-on cord-and-plug-connected 120V circuits and saying nope.  The NEC rationale is to herd you into using a subpanel instead of a bunch of parallel circuits (not least, so there's a single shut-off for maintenance and emergency response; of course they don't require this where it's impossible.) Break this logic by putting either circuit on a switch.

Comment: Well I do have outside receptacles attached to the house. Can I tie the additional, general use receptacle (near the dedicated pool one)  into that circuit some how?

Comment: Also, I still don't understand with the switch.. so as long as there is a maintenance switch like this,Intermatic WP1220C 2 Gang 2-1/4-Inch Weatherproof Box, Clear http://www.walmart.com/ip/Intermatic-Inc-WP1220C-Intermatic-Inc-WP1220C-Plastic-In-Use-Receptacle-Cover-2-Gang-In-Use-Polycarbonate-Weatherproof/21969754 to the outlet used by pool, i can use another circuit for the general use receptacle?

Comment: You're up against NEC 225.30, which *on its face*  prohibits more than one feeder or branch circuit to the same outside location.  Please google that.  This comes up a lot and my usual approach is to try to alter conditions to snake it under one of the exceptions, such as a circuit switched or controlled at the house.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was trying to find the NEC article that specified this scenario, but was having trouble. I will read up on this and follow up with anymore questions.

Comment: My understanding of 225.30 is it only applies to *structures* -- you can feed two circuits to a single set of outdoor receptacles because there's no structure involved...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The way the ECMweb article talked about it, it seemed like it would be applicable to a post, especially one near a structure.  Wouldn't do to bypass 225.30 by sticking a 4x4 post *right next* to a structure!  In any case this is one of those AHJ roulette situations, where they could go either way.  You'd want to know.

Comment: @Harper -- agreed, although the Code has worse cases of AHJ roulette ;)