# Can I use a shared conduit for an above-ground pool setup, or not?

Tags: wiring, conduit, pool

I've been reading [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/113171/13638) to a question that more or less is my situation.  The difference being that I already have a 100A sub-panel (fed by a 50A breaker from the house) in an outbuilding from which I intend to supply the pool circuits.

I believe I am required to run two circuits to the pool area, one for the pump and one for a "convenience outlet".  I need 20A for each.  So to me, that's two sets of 12awg THHN in a conduit.  But it seems like the aforementioned NEC 225.30 is going to further force me to make that a single circuit running out to the pool area with some sort of box out there to split it.

Leaving aside the exceptions available via playing with the configuration...am I getting this right as far as the basic requirement is concerned?

As requested, here's the pump's label:
[image]

The pump has a short cord with a twist-lock plug.

EDIT:  pump will be outside, on a small slab.  I intend to run electric underground in conduit up to the area of the pump, and then come up to a post where I'll mount the fixtures.  Maybe two if the 6-10' and 10-20' problem doesn't afford me a way to do it all at the same emergence.

Comment: How deep is the pool 42 inches or less is seasonal and doesn’t require a convenience outlet the pump usually has a 20’ GFCI cord in this case as required by code. Different rules for different pools.

Comment: @EdBeal 54", so it's considered "permanent", at least in Ohio where I live.

Comment: Yes 42” is the limit for seasonal ,  article 680 swimming pools, fountains and other installations: (is the code for pools) what type of pump/ filter unit are you using? In some cases a separate convenience receptacle is not required a duplex will suffice, example a 20 amp circuit at least 6’ away but within 20’ with a duplex. We still need the info on the pump if cord and plug connected with double insulation or hardwired  I had a similar pool in Dayton and the code has not changed much since then.

Comment: Yes -- is the pool pump permanently mounted, or cord-and-plug connected?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The pump has a twist-lock plug.

Comment: @EdBeal Added some information.

Comment: @DonBoitnott -- can you describe more about the location the pump lives in? Is it outdoors, or sheltered by some sort of poolhouse?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel edited in more info.